# Httpclient set post without actual posting

Tags: java, post, https, request, httpclient

I have the following code, where I simply make a request over `https` to a `localhost`

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("keystore.p12")),
                "password".toCharArray());
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray()).build());
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();

        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                "https://localhost:1810/bot", String.class);
```

but now I want to send a Post request with body, so I added

```
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://localhost:1810/bot");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity(" { \"message\": \"hello\", \"sessionID\": \"\", \"timestamp\": \"1480596337583\" } ");
        post.setEntity(params);
```

but now I don't know how I can combine those. All I found was `Httpclient.execute(post`) but that would send it as a `http` request. 
Is there a way to set `Httpclient` to a `Post` method without actually sending it because I have to give it as a parameter in
`ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);` 
or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a HttpHost, like this

```
HttpHost host = new HttpHost("domain", 443, "https")
```

and then use the execute() method that takes a host argument

```
httpClient.execute(host, post)
```

Comment: but that would send a Post request without using the certificate right?

in here
    `ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                httpClient);`


i have to add the httpClient, so i need to combine `HttpClient` with `HttpPost` without actually sending them